# Team Foundation ServeR Project checking Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Always display this message,`All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks. The changes have been undone by the server`.
What is this?
How can i resolve it?

Thankyou

Comment: Try **Getting Latest Version Recursive** and then checkin? Have a copy of your files before that...

Comment: what is this problem? its my saver problem?

Comment: Its basically resource sharing thing.. The same resource could also be checked out and edited by someone else and they might have checked in the same after changes to server and it creates conflict.. Thus TFS asks you to get its latest version, merge the conflicts if any and then check in.. But always better to keep a copy before getting latest version, as sometimes it might replace your content.. So did that work?

Comment: agree with you :) thanks for the advice

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Did you update/add items from outside of VS before check in?

Comment: no no, checking for,         after done